# Filling gaps of missing rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm using this query to average a value (performance) over 3-minute intervals of an hour:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', created) AS created,
  (extract(minute FROM created)::int / 3) minute_part,
  worker,
  AVG(performance)
FROM perf_stats
WHERE
  group_id = 'foo' AND 
  worker = 'bar' AND
  created > '1.1.2021 19:00:00' AND
  created < '1.1.2021 20:00:00'
GROUP BY 1, 2, worker
ORDER BY 1, 2, worker;
```

This returns the following result set for the sample data set:

| created | minute_part | worker | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 10 | bar | 3 |

Now I'd like to fill in zeros for the performance when there are no rows satisfying the query. Resulting in this result set:

| created | minute_part | worker | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 0 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 1 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 2 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 3 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 4 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 5 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 6 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 7 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 8 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 9 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 10 | bar | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 11 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 12 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 13 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 14 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 15 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 16 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 17 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 18 | bar | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | 19 | bar | 0 |

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE perf_stats
(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    worker TEXT NOT NULL,
    performance DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IDX_PERFSTATS_CREATED on perf_stats(group_id, created);
```

**Sample Data:**

```
INSERT INTO perf_stats (group_id, worker, performance, created) 
VALUES('foo', 'bar', 2, '1.1.2021 19:30:00');

INSERT INTO perf_stats (group_id, worker, performance, created) 
VALUES('foo', 'bar', 4, '1.1.2021 19:31:00');
```

I've experimented with `generate_series` but did not get it working so far.

Comment: it would help if you provide some sample data and wanted result

Comment: Added the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

ou can gve this one try.
It joins the generated series(here fixed from 0 to 59) and cross joins this with the qery you got.

Then case when check if an average fort that minute is available, else sets it to 0

> ```
> WITH genser AS (SELECT * FROM generate_series(0,59) AS a)
> SELECT t1.created,a as minute_part,t1.worker, CASE WHEN genser.a =  minute_part THEN avg ELSe 0 ENd  as avg_perfo FROM genser CROSS JOIN (
> SELECT date_trunc('hour', created) AS created, (extract(minute FROM created)::int / 3) minute_part, worker, AVG(performance)
> FROM perf_stats
> WHERE group_id = 'foo' AND worker = 'bar' and created > '1.1.2021 19:00:00' and created < '1.1.2021 20:00:00'
> GROUP BY 1, 2, worker
> ORDER BY 1, 2, worker) t1 
> ORDER By created, worker,minute_part;
> ```
>
> ```
> created             | minute_part | worker | avg_perfo
> :------------------ | ----------: | :----- | :--------
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           0 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           1 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           2 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           3 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           4 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           5 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           6 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           7 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           8 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |           9 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          10 | bar    | 3        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          11 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          12 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          13 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          14 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          15 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          16 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          17 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          18 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          19 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          20 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          21 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          22 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          23 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          24 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          25 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          26 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          27 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          28 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          29 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          30 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          31 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          32 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          33 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          34 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          35 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          36 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          37 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          38 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          39 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          40 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          41 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          42 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          43 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          44 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          45 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          46 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          47 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          48 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          49 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          50 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          51 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          52 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          53 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          54 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          55 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          56 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          57 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          58 | bar    | 0        
> 2021-01-01 19:00:00 |          59 | bar    | 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=43c990f0fff6b75b1ac0736e24428aa5)*